# Android USB mount size

Tags: android, root

I have an Android device, that has a variation of "su" binary, which does not echo stdout of the passed command. So, I can not see what does 'su -c df' tells me. Is there any way to get size of the USB flash mounted to the device without using df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following standard methods to discover the size of sdcard:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long size = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getBlockCount();
```

So, you see that the only thing you need is a path to your mount point.